# Can pass cv2 blobFromImage to keras model predict?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, opencv, keras

I am making an application on TensorFlow and openCV.

I know that you can pass a keras model (.h5 or .hdf5) to .pb and thus read it with cv2. But I'm wondering if cv.blobFromImage could be used to Keras model.predict(...) method.

If I try to pass it directly, an error appears. Since blob returns in a different order than necessary in the keras model.

For example:

```py
frameSrc = cv2.imread('example.jpg')

# Correct Keras model input.
frameDst = cv2.resize(frameSrc.copy(), (256, 256), interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
frameDst = cv2.cvtColor(frameDst, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
frameDst = np.array([frameDst])
frameDst = frameDst / 255.
# frameDst.shape = (1, 256, 256, 3)
        
# cv2 blob.
blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frameSrc.copy(), scalefactor=1/255., size=(256, 256), swapRB=False)
# blob.shape = (1, 3, 256, 256)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keras expects the format in `(batch_size, height, width, number_of_channels)`, given TF backend.

So the blob.shape needs to be in this format, not in `(batch_size,channels,height,width)` like you see above.

You can swap the axes to achieve a suitable input format:

```
blob = np.transpose(blob,(0,2,3,1))
blob.shape (1,256,256,3)
```